# Commit behavior and atomicity in python sqlite3 module

Tags: python, sqlite, commit, atomic

If I want to create a table and insert a new entry in another table, can this 
be made atomic in the sqlite module?

Refering to the docs at http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html:

> By default, the sqlite3 module opens transactions implicitly before a
>   Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e.
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE), and commits transactions implicitly
>   before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than
>   SELECT or the aforementioned).
>
> So if you are within a transaction and issue a command like CREATE
>   TABLE ..., VACUUM, PRAGMA, the sqlite3 module will commit implicitly
>   before executing that command. There are two reasons for doing that.
>   The first is that some of these commands don’t work within
>   transactions. The other reason is that sqlite3 needs to keep track of
>   the transaction state (if a transaction is active or not).

I'm not sure if this second paragraph is meant to apply to automatically started
transactions or to both manual and automatic ones.

Sqlite docs http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html tell us that manual transactions
would not commit until an explicit COMMIT:

> Transactions can be started manually using the BEGIN command. Such
>   transactions usually persist until the next COMMIT or ROLLBACK
>   command.

So suppose we have something like this:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(fdb) 
cur = con.cursor()

sql = 'begin transaciton'
cur.execute(sql)    

sql = 'CREATE TABLE some-table ...
cur.execute(sql)

# *** is there an implicit commit at this point ?! ***

sql = 'INSERT INTO  another-table ...
cur.execute(sql)

con.commit()
```

Would this be atomic, or would python sqlite make a commit after the `create table` statement?
Is there a way to make it atomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python SQLite3 libary inserts automatic commits even where none are needed.

To make your entire transaction atomic, use any other Python SQLite wrapper, such as, e.g., [APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/).

Comment: I'm testing by opening two separate sqlite3 shells and running transactions in one and checking results in the other. And yes you're correct.

Comment: If sqlite3 is quashing atomicity just like that they should at least highlight such an issue in the documentation.

Comment: There's currently an [open bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740) regarding this issue, but from the looks of the comments nothing's likely to happen for Python 2.x (due to backwards compatibility concerns) and for Python 3.x ... well, it's been several years and there doesn't seem to be much movement on it. It's also worth noting (from that bug's comments) that merely inserting comments before DML statements causes implicit commits with the sqlite3 module (in other words, it's basically broken).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this atomically. The Python SQLite library  implicitly issues a `COMMIT` whenever you execute a `CREATE TABLE ..` statement, because SQLite does not *support* executing the `CREATE TABLE ..` statement while a transaction is active.

You can test this by opening the database in both the python interpreter and the `sqlite3` command line tool. As soon as you issue the `CREATE TABLE ..` statement, you can run a `.schema` command in the `sqlite3` command line tool and see the result of that statement.

Note that this means that anything you did in the transaction *before* the `CREATE TABLE ..` statement will also have been committed. To look it in another way, the `CREATE TABLE ..` statement first commits, then starts a completely *new* transaction.

Comment: Thanks - so is order significant?! If we do the insert first and then the create table, then we can get atomicity for this specific case?

Comment: No, you'd still get two separate transactions. The table creation could fail, and your inserts are still being committed. Try it yourself; do an insert (do not commit), then create the *same table* again. You'll get an operational error (table already exists), but the insert will have been committed.

Comment: It's just the Python library that does the commit; SQLite itself will never do an automatic commit when you are in an explicit transaction.

Comment: @CL.: You are correct, I misread the quoted documentation. Updated my answer.

Comment: SQLite supports any DML and DDL statements inside a transaction.

Comment: @CL.: It's behaviour is undefined, as far as I can make out. Try to create a table and an index on that table in a transaction, for example. DDL-in-transaction-support is, at best, undocumented and incomplete.

Comment: Works fine (outside of Python). All changes to the database file (whether DML or DDL) are made the same way (because the entire file is exclusively locked anyway).

Comment: Interesting, support must have been updated then. You may want to track [python issue 10740](http://bugs.python.org/issue10740) (just discovered) to see if the python module will be updated to support that!

Comment: @CL.: I see that `DROP TABLE` is not transactional, and there are there is at least one `PRAGMA` statement that is explicitly a no-op within a transaction.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` works fine inside transactions. `PRAGMA foreign_keys` is documented that way because it's an exception.

Comment: @CL.: I understood from the ticket I linked that dropping tables wasn't working; I didn't test it myself.

Comment: torsten's description is not about SQLite but about Python's behaviour (the `DROP` was not rolled back because Python autocommitted it).

Comment: @CL.: Ah, yes, misread that part then. Cool, hopefully that patch will make it into Python soon.