# Python with SQLite3: select does not display any data

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sqlite

I am writing a very simply database using python and sqlite3. And when I created a table and some data I wanted to display this data using (in terminal) command "Select * From Data", but no data appears, although I checked using other methods that the data is inserted to the table.

How I create my table and data:

```
db = connect('database.db')
db_cursor = db.cursor()
db_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data(Id INT, Name TEXT, City TEXT)")
db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Data VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'XYZ')")
```

If I do:

```
db_cursor.execute("Select * From Data")
print self.db_cursor.fetchall()
```

the data is displayed.

But when I run a command line and try to do:

```
sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> SELECT * FROM Data;
```

no data appears. I checked using

```
sqlite> .tables
```

that table is generated correctly.
Why sqlite3 run from command line does not display data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction before it is permanently part of the database:

```
db.commit()
```

You can use the database connection [as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) to commit automatically if a block of code executed successfully:

```
with db:
    db_cursor = db.cursor()
    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Data VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'XYZ')")
```

Note that DDL statements (creating tables and other data definitions) are [automatically committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642956/commit-behavior-and-atomicity-in-python-sqlite3-module), which is why you saw the table in the database, but not the new row.