# sqlite3 insert not committing

Tags: python, sqlite

When trying to insert rows into a table with a unique index, it appears to simply silently not insert.

I've captured the behaviour in the following program: on the second call to test_insert I should get an integrity violation on the unique key. But nothing. Also, if I take the `c.execute(query, [id_to_test])` line and duplicate itself below it, I do receive the proper integrity constraint as expected. What's happening here?

```
import sqlite3

def test_insert(id_to_test):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    query = '''INSERT INTO test(unique_id)
               VALUES(?)'''

    c.execute(query, [id_to_test])

def setup_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test''')

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE test (unique_id text)''')
    c.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_unique_id ON test (unique_id)''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_table()
    test_insert('test_id')
    test_insert('test_id')
    test_insert('test_id')
```

Comment: you need to call `conn.commit()`. read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Isn't calling commit necessary?

Comment: heh, I tried calling commit on the cursor and it said it didn't exist. Also http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/ didn't say anything about commit

Comment: you need to call it on the connection and not the cursor. (i'd put more trust in the official documentation of the module...)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yeah, I can see that now. What confuses me here is that the table creation stuff worked without commit

Comment: there is an explanation for this in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643215/4954037 hope that helps. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

At the end of database operations, commit the changes to the database:

```
conn.commit()
```